# Tackling working directory for find command

Tags: find

I am passing a pdf file to a script and extracting various parts (e.g. path, name, extension) so that I can find some associated commentaries stored in org files.

Would like to tackle files in the current working directory where there is no path included (e.g. `file.pdf` rather than `./file.pdf` or `/path/file.pdf`).  Currently
I have a problem because I have to set `fdir`.

```
for fl in "$@"; do
   fnme=${fl##*/}
   fext=${fl##*.}
   fdir=${fl%/*}
   fnam=${fnme%.*}
   
   find "$fdir" -type f -name "${fnam}.org"
done
```

Comment: What is the problem? What happens, what do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use the utility `dirname`, it would properly return `.` for a pathname argument with no directory path in it:

```bsh
for pathname do
    name=$( basename "$pathname" )
    find "$( dirname "$pathname" ) -name "${name%.*}.org" -type f
done
```

If you know you're dealing with filenames that end in `.pdf`, then you may use

```bsh
for pathname do
    find "$( dirname "$pathname" ) -name "$( basename "$pathname" .pdf ).org" -type f
done
```

If you have the `zsh` shell, you may use

```bsh
for pathname
    find $pathname:h -name $pathname:t:r.org -type f
done
```

`:h` returns the "head" of a pathname, i.e. the directory path components, while `:t` returns the "tail", i.e. the filename component.  You get the extension-less "root" of a filename with `:r`.

If you're only interested in looking in the same directory as the original file, then you also need to limit the recursion that `find` does.  You can  do this with `-maxdepth 1` with most current implementations of `find`.

Answer (score 0):

You could default to `./` as the search directory if `$fdir` is empty.   e.g. something like:

```
find "${fdir:-./}"  -type f -name "$fnam.org"
```

Comment: Thank you,  Do not use these constructs much, but could be quite suitable in this case.  Thanks again.

Comment: But using `fdir=${fl%/*}` with `fl=edvart.pdf`, does not result in an empty `fdir` because I am getting `fdir` to be `edvart.pdf`.

Comment: So check if $fdir contains a `/`.  If it doesn't, replace it with `./`.  If it does, strip off the filename portion, if any. This should be obvious: you know you need a directory in that part of the find command, so make sure you have one to use there.   That kind of thing is the primary function of a shell script - to make sure that other programs (programs which do the actual work) are supplied with the data they need, and that the programs are run when needed, in the order that they are needed.